# Selenium (Maybe headless) on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

i have had a rough time getting my scripts to work on my raspberry pi zero w and the last program i need installed requires selenium. This script was designed for windows 10 + python 2.7 because i make my scripts in this environment.

I was wondering if it is possible to use selenium on a raspberry pi zero w and preferably headless if possible.

I can't find any info, help or guidelines online anywhere and have no idea how to use pip in raspbian (if it even has pip).

Comment: You can but I would not recommend. Because chrome requires decent memory usage. A 300-400MB stress on a Rasberry PI is not what you want. You probably want to launch a external grid and let your rasp connect to it. But otherwise it is possible to use Chrome headless and python in Rasberry PI. You need Python, Pip and chromium installed RPI

Comment: Okay but how would i go on about to download the chromedriver / geckodriver / firefox driver. I can't find any that are compatible and only know the commands to get chrome into headless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't. You can install `pip` with `apt install python-pip`, you'll probably need to `sudo` that command unless you login as `root`.

Then you can just open a terminal and use the `pip install` command to get selenium. If that doesn't work you can try running `python -m pip install` instead.