# Airbnb pricing with selenium on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a working script that runs on my laptop (macos). It watches pricing on an airbnb link with selenium, uses chromedriver and stores prices for a link using gspread.

In an attempt to migrate this to a raspberrypi zero w running the latest raspberry pi os w/desktop to run on a cronjob with an interval i am having some issues getting chrome/chromedriver to work as a headless instance to interact with the airbnb website and get pricing. Instead of running the cronjob on my laptop (which may be asleep) the rpi is just standing ready to do this job for me 24/7. I have the code below.

In reading others work with a similar situations I have found common workarounds that are not functioning for me.

https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/01/selenium-chromedriver-for-raspberrypi (installed and not functioning)

https://onthegoalways.com/blog/running-selenium-webdriver-on-raspberry-pi-zero/#solution-%EF%B8%8F (similar situation, solution not functioning)

Code:

```
#airbnb3.py

##for pricing on a given Airbnb
##upload to gsheet and publish a chart


import gspread
import requests
import re
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Authenticate and connect to the Google Sheets API

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('JSON.json', SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Your spreadsheet ID
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'SHEETKEY'
# Name of the worksheet you want to work with
WORKSHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1'  # Change this to your worksheet's name

# setup selenium
#chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

service=Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
try:
    thisDict = {
        "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/46777627": ['myAirbnb']
    }

    # Get today's date and time
    today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%x')
    today_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%X')

    for url, spot in thisDict.items():
        # navigate to airbnb
        driver.get(url)
        # wait until the price block loads
        timeout = 10
        expectation = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._tyxjp1'))
        price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(expectation)
        # print the price
        match = re.search(r'\$([0-9,.]+)', price_element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        price = match.group(1)

        # Open the desired worksheet
        worksheet = client.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID).worksheet(WORKSHEET_NAME)

        # Find the header row
        header_row = worksheet.row_values(1)
        #print(header_row)
        col_index = header_row.index('Date') + 1 
        next_available_row = len(worksheet.col_values(col_index)) + 1
        worksheet.update_cell(next_available_row, 1, today_date)
        worksheet.update_cell(next_available_row, 2, today_time)
        worksheet.update_cell(next_available_row, 3, price)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

The error i most often get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/airbnb3.py", line 39, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 122, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

I reviewed other stack posts that are very similar like:
[Webscraping using Selenium on Raspberry Pi Zero: Status code was: -4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326452/webscraping-using-selenium-on-raspberry-pi-zero-status-code-was-4)

and:

[Selenium (Maybe headless) on raspberry pi zero w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675769/selenium-maybe-headless-on-raspberry-pi-zero-w)

Their solutions did not resolve the issue as i tried them.

I have verified the driver is in $PATH.

Any help on understanding this error is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the time.